# Is the Kelvin-Stokes theorem an "identity"?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, terminology

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_%28mathematics%29):

> An identity is an equality relation A = B, such that A and B contain
>   some variables and give the same result when the variables are
>   substituted by any values (usually numbers).

With this definition in mind, can the gradient, curl, and divergence theorems be correctly called vector calculus identities?

Comment: Yes. The values are functions/vector fields and domains/manifolds with suitable properties (sufficiently smooth).

Comment: Please feel free to submit this as an answer.